# PHP file upload image not loading to server

Tags: php, image, upload

I am attempting to upload a image file via php and it is not working:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "/home/NAME/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir);

$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

This is what is returned, but no file actually uploads. Anyone know what is going on? Thanks

```
Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => followers.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpKsuz1B [error] => 0 [size] => 127008 ) )
```

Comment: Does the target directory (*/home/NAME/uploads/*) have the correct read/write permissions?

Comment: yes I have chmod 777-ed it

Comment: Do you have access to tmp dir?

Comment: yes I believe it is /tmp/ correct? the upload is not happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir);
```

To:

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $target_dir);` to `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_dir);`

`move_uploaded_file` needs the temporary file name in order for it to upload, not the original name of the file, since it needs a resource to move.

Answer (score 1):

The uploaded file is actually `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']`, this is the file you need to move.

A good way to go about this is:

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];    
$destFile = '/dest/directory/' . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

// You'll now have your temp file in destination directory, with the original image's name
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $destFile);
```

A good practice is to keep your file names unique, because you never know when different images may be named `image01.jpg` (more often than one would hope).

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];    

$destDir  = '/dest/directory/';
$destName = uniqid() . '_' . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$destFile = $destDir . $destName;

// Temp file is now in destination directory, with a unique filename  
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $destFile);
```